# Convert timestamp to a date-time format in R

Tags: r, timestamp, lubridate

I have a dataset, with a column with automatically generated timestamps in the format.

```
head(tweets$V2)

[1] Fri Oct 30 18:33:50 +0000 2015 Fri Oct 30 18:33:51 +0000 2015 Fri Oct 30 18:33:52 +0000 2015
[4] Fri Oct 30 18:33:54 +0000 2015 Fri Oct 30 18:33:55 +0000 2015 Fri Oct 30 18:33:56 +0000 2015
```

I want to convert these to a `POSIX` type time-date format. Any pointers on how do I go about with this?

After converting these to a standard time format, I wanted to observe trends in the subjects of the tweets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `?strptime` for more details:

```
tweets$V2 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(tweets$V2, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"))
```

This will convert the strigs in `POSIXct` format with the default time zone of your system. If you want to specify a different timezone, include the `tz` argument.

```
a <- c("Fri Oct 30 18:33:50 +0000 2015")
as.POSIXct(strptime(a, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"))
[1] "2015-10-30 14:33:50 EDT"

as.POSIXct(strptime(a, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT"))
[1] "2015-10-30 18:33:50 GMT"
```

Note: Convert the column with `as.character` if it is of class `factor`